# Process layouts and userflows

Tags: users

I was wondering if there is a difference between process layouts and userflows when it comes to ux? Or are they the same but can be mentioned in either name?

Comment: I don't think I've come across the term "process layout" in the context of UX. Do you have an example of this term being used?

Comment: In addition, you'll have to define - ideally via an example - what you consider a user flow... some do not see it as the same as others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Process layouts** describe **real-world** or **abstract** processes without accounting for the system supporting them. For example, you may define that each task in your development process goes through 3 main stages:

- Design
- Implementation
- QA

The term *user* in **user flows** denotes how the user progresses through the supporting **system**. The user flow for the process above may be:

- Choose a project [projects page]
- Choose a task [task list page]
- Change stage [task page]

The whole process mentioned above is practically realised in the last step of the user flow. So in this case there isn't 1:1 mapping between the two (which is common when the process is of abstract nature).